# segmentation fault while trying to write to element of struct array

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct item{
    int man;
};
int writeto(struct item **itens, int n){
    *itens = malloc(sizeof(struct item)*n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        itens[i]->man = i*2;
    }

}
int main(){
    struct item* itens;
    writeto(&itens,2);
    printf("%d\n",itens[0] );
    printf("%d\n",itens[1] );
    return 0;
}
```

Hello. I create an array of struct itens and then allocate memory for that array inside the function and fill it. the first element works ([0]) and I can access it outside the function, however, the second never works. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages. Please use *either* tag, but not both. As your example is pure C, I removed the C++ tag.

Comment: You'll also want to write C functions that return allocated structures instead of things that mutate double-pointers passed in. Be sure to compile with warnings enabled (`-Wall` usually) to point out any mistakes before they end up bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're accessing `itens` wrong here:

```
itens[i]->man = i*2;
```

`itens` is a pointer to an array of `struct item`. Instead, do this:

```
(*itens)[i].man = i*2;
```

Also, you're printing wrong, too.

Instead of:

```
printf("%d\n",itens[0] );
printf("%d\n",itens[1] );
```

use:

```
printf("%d\n", itens[0].man);
printf("%d\n", itens[1].man);
```

Comment: that was the key, thanks! I actually tried to do earlier *itens[i].man but it always complained about it being a pointer and that I should use -> ...

Comment: @peterman You have to use the parentheses. If this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: I'll accept it in 6 minutes, otherwise I'd have done it by now :)

Comment: Also, I wrote a function like this: void write(struct item *item){item->man = 5;}, how would I pass the itens[i] to it? I keep trying to do write(itens[i]) but it keeps segmentation fault

Comment: @s-s-anne related to the previous, that function `void write(struct item *item){item->man = 5;}` has the same problem as the previous, that the first works and the second just doesn't...what might be the issue?

Comment: @peter `&itens[i]` or `itens + i`. Your function is correct.

Comment: @s-s-anne &itens[i] doesn't work because that argument would be of type ** and not *

Comment: @peter Not in `main`. If you're asking about `writeto` then you can use `&(*itens)[i]`.